# Auth wih jwt and passportjs, passport.authenticate never reaches my JwtStrategy

Tags: node.js, jwt, passport.js

I'm having trouble authenticating with passportjs and jwt. I'm sending an authorization header in a get request and reciveve an Unauthorized response. My first thought was that I'm probably messing up something with the token, so I'm trying to log the jwt_payload.

It seems to me like passport.authenticate() does not even run any of the code in my passport.js file, as console.log(jwt_payload) below never logs anything

/config/passport.js

```
module.exports = function(passport) {
    let opts = {};
    opts.jwtFromRequest = ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken();
    opts.secretOrKey = config.secret;

    passport.use(new JwtStrategy(opts, (jwt_payload, done) => {
        console.log(jwt_payload);
        User.getUserById(jwt_payload._id, (err, user) => {
            if(err){
                return done(err,false);
            }
            if(user){
                return done(null,user);
            } else {
                return done(null, false);
            }
        });
    }));
}
```

The passport.use(...) clause above must however be doing something, if i remove it i get an error of Unknown authentication strategy "jwt"

Below is the code for my passport setup and passport.authenticate() call.

/routes/users.js

```
const passport = require('passport');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const config = require('../config/database');

router.get('/profile', passport.authenticate('jwt', {session:false}), (req, res, next) => {
  res.json({user: req.user});
});
```

app.js

```
const passport = require('passport');

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

require('./config/passport')(passport);
```

Comment: If you put a `console.log("test")` in there does it hit that? Maybe it's not extracting the JWT token properly and the console output is blank? (bit of a long shot)

Comment: I've tried, and no it doesn't make a difference. Thanks tho!

Comment: Hey @shaz, did you ever figure out the solution to this? Literally stuck on the same issue right now.

Comment: I'm sad to say, no. It was a hobby project and I haven't touched it since. If you figure it out - please leave a comment and I might take that project up again